# Tensorflow subclass keras with mulitple output shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
        self.build(input_shape=[None, 1])

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        return self.dense(inputs)

MyModel().summary()
```

[image]

The model plot does not work as well:

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='model_1.png', show_shapes=True)
```

I tried this code on several tensorflow versions 2.3.0, 2.3.1, and 2.4.1 and every time the `output shape` is `multiple`! Is it a bug? Any fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **not the bug**. Generally, we can't assume anything about the structure of a subclassed Model. That's why you can't get output shape in `.summary()` in model **Subclasses** API same as **Functional** or **Sequential** API like.

But here is a workaround to achieve this. You can achieve this as the following method.

```
import tensorflow as tf 

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
        self.build(input_shape=[None, 1])

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        return self.dense(inputs)

    def build_graph(self):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1))
        return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))

MyModel().build_graph().summary()
```

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 1)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 2         
=================================================================
Total params: 2
Trainable params: 2
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Same as plotting the model.

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    MyModel().build_graph()                     
)
```

Comment: I remark that even in the tensorboard, the graph does not show all the layers, specially the `BatchNormalization` layer.

Comment: That is nothing to do with this, but a different issue. Try this `BatchNormalization._USE_V2_BEHAVIOR = False` after import the bn.

Comment: AFAIK, it happed in `tf 2.0, 2.1` but fixed in later `2.3` >=.

Comment: I fixed it by installing `tf 2.4.1`