# How to plot Graph-neural-network model-graph when using tensorflow Model Subclass API with spektral layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, graph-neural-network

I am unable to plot graph-neural-networking. I have seen few related questions([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66927645/tensorflow-subclass-keras-with-mulitple-output-shape), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427583/how-do-i-plot-a-keras-tensorflow-subclassing-api-model), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887785/how-to-visualize-nested-tf-keras-model-subclassed-api-gan-model-with-plot-mo)) to this topic but their answers do not apply to graph-neural-networks.

What makes it different is that the input vector include objects of different dimensions e.g. properties matrix dimension is `[n_nodes, n_node_features]`, adjacency matrix dimension is `[n_nodes, n_nodes]` etc. Here is the example of my Model:

```
class GIN0(Model):
    def __init__(self, channels, n_layers):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = GINConv(channels, epsilon=0, mlp_hidden=[channels, channels])
        self.convs = []
        for _ in range(1, n_layers):
            self.convs.append(
                GINConv(channels, epsilon=0, mlp_hidden=[channels, channels])
            )
        self.pool = GlobalAvgPool()
        self.dense1 = Dense(channels, activation="relu")
        self.dropout = Dropout(0.5)
        self.dense2 = Dense(channels, activation="relu")

    def call(self, inputs):
        x, a, i = inputs
        x = self.conv1([x, a])
        for conv in self.convs:
            x = conv([x, a])
        x = self.pool([x, i])
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        return self.dense2(x)
```

One of the answers in [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427583/how-do-i-plot-a-keras-tensorflow-subclassing-api-model) suggested to add `build_graph` function as follows:

```
class my_model(Model):
    def __init__(self, dim):
        super(my_model, self).__init__()
        self.Base  = VGG16(input_shape=(dim), include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')
        self.GAP   = L.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.BAT   = L.BatchNormalization()
        self.DROP  = L.Dropout(rate=0.1)
        self.DENS  = L.Dense(256, activation='relu', name = 'dense_A')
        self.OUT   = L.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        x  = self.Base(inputs)
        g  = self.GAP(x)
        b  = self.BAT(g)
        d  = self.DROP(b)
        d  = self.DENS(d)
        return self.OUT(d)
    
    # AFAIK: The most convenient method to print model.summary() 
    # similar to the sequential or functional API like.
    def build_graph(self):
        x = Input(shape=(dim))
        return Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))

dim = (124,124,3)
model = my_model((dim))
model.build((None, *dim))
model.build_graph().summary()
```

However, I am not sure how to define dim or Input Layer using `tf.keras.layers.Input` for such a hybrid data-structure as described above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think's it's entirely doable. What's shape of your training paris (`x, y`)?

Comment: Is this your source scripts? https://github.com/danielegrattarola/spektral/blob/e84ff85c039ab6990d89185d7f6ccbf0ad8bb7d6/examples/graph_prediction/tud_gin.py.

Comment: i am working on a single example. The structure is the list of properties matrix( dimension is [n_nodes, n_node_features]) and adjacency matrix (dimension is [n_nodes, n_nodes]).  I am using graph convolutional layers from github.com/danielegrattarola/spektral/blob/…

Comment: I would like to add an answer but there's some issue on the spektral side (with `GINConv`), [ISSUE](https://github.com/danielegrattarola/spektral/issues/379). I think you should ask there. The ploting issue is not general and it has that dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the minimal code to plot such subclass multi-input model. Note, as stated in the comment above, there are some [issue](https://github.com/danielegrattarola/spektral/issues/379) of your `GINConv` which is from [`spektral`](https://github.com/danielegrattarola/spektral) and it's not related to the main query. So, I will give general soluton of such multi-input modeling scenarios. To make it work with your `speckral`, please reach to the package author for further discussion.

---

From `specktral` repo, [here](https://github.com/danielegrattarola/spektral/blob/e84ff85c039ab6990d89185d7f6ccbf0ad8bb7d6/examples/graph_prediction/tud_gin.py#L42), I got the idea the shape of the input tensors.

```
x, y = next(iter(loader_tr))

bs_x = list(x[0].shape)
bs_y = list(x[1].shape)
bs_z = list(x[2].shape)

bs_x, bs_y, bs_z
([1067, 4], [1067, 1067], [1067])
```

Similar model, it also takes same amount of inputs and with same shape. But without `GINConv`.

```
class GIN0(Model):
    def __init__(self, channels, n_layers):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(channels, 3, activation='relu')
        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(channels, 3, activation='relu')

        self.dense1 = Dense(channels, activation="relu")
        self.dropout = Dropout(0.5)
        self.dense2 = Dense(n_out, activation="softmax")

    def call(self, inputs):
        x, a, i = inputs

        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
        a = self.conv2(a)
        a = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(a)

        x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([a, x, i])
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        return self.dense2(x)
    
    def build_graph(self):
        x = tf.keras.Input(shape=bs_x)
        y = tf.keras.Input(shape=bs_y)
        z = tf.keras.Input(shape=bs_z)
        return tf.keras.Model(
            inputs=[x, y, z], 
            outputs=self.call([x, y, z])
        )
```

```
model = GIN0(channels, layers)
model.build(
    [
        (None, *bs_x), 
        (None, *bs_y), 
        (None, *bs_z)
    ]
)

# OK
model.build_graph().summary()

# OK
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    model.build_graph(), show_shapes=True
)
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem. I am trying to understand why shape of layer goes like (None, *bs_x) e.g. why None and why reference to the list bs_x and not the list itself?

Comment: The issue is not really in GINConv as my model.predict would work fine. Only when the model is built with the shape, the input to `call(inputs)` function in **GIN0 call** is no longer sparse matrix. The build function uses `base_layer_utils.generate_placeholders_from_shape(shape)` in **tensorflow Model class build function** and it doesn't know how to create sparse matrix. A possible fix of this issue would be to overwrite build function and add functionality to create sparse matrix rather than dense matrix.

Comment: @innat I have similar problem with dimension of pooling layers in spektral package. Could you please help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75478893/issue-with-using-pooling-layers-in-spektral-package-for-graph-neural-networks